# Reading the data from a glucometer externally with a microcontroller or arduino board

Tags: usb

What would be the easiest way to read data from a USB glucose meter externally with a microcontroller or arduino board and not with the software that is provided. So how could I incercept the digital signals that are being sent out? I don't have a particular glucometer in mind has I want you guys suggestions in buying one.
Thanks for your anticipated response. 
Best regards,

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to buy Bayer *Contour TS* that has usb cable and software for windows. If you want to read data by using microcontroller or arduino you must know something about **UART (RX,TX)**.

If you can not do anything just focus on making a glucose meter. I suggest you to try to do **Microchip Glucose Meter**. It looks easy to do because it's open source so you can read data easily

Hope you got answer.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I think I am going to use it as a backup plan.